# no display on. Asus graphic card

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I have Asus 210 ddr3 1gb graphic card on this day its not showing display when I check graphic card going regular heat but no display after I check without graphic card showing display how to I fix it. I have changed integrated graphic in bios no result

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the proper drivers from the Asus website before using the external card, and disabling integrated graphics/enabling external graphics from your BIOS.